# What is linear constraint?

Tags: linear-programming

Is linear constraint a constraint in form of linear equation?

I used  equation $f_i(\alpha x + \beta y) = \alpha f_i(x) + \beta f_i(y)$ to test linearity of constraint . For $f_i(x) =x+5$ test failed. For $f_i(x) =2x$ test passed.

What I don't get is $x+5$ is linear equation then, why it failed the test.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "linear constraint" is occasionally a linear equation but more ususually a linear inequality $e.g.$ $$2x+3y \le 47$$ or $$7x+13y-8z \ge 677.$$